# Diff local directory and svn repository without checking out the files

Tags: svn, diff

Is it possible to diff a local directory (not a svn checkout) and a remote svn repository without checking out the repository to another local directory beforehand?

I need it for linux (debian) but the question is in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/vi/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html). `svn diff` can not use irrelevant paths or URLs as parameters, they have to be part of repository or Working Copy.

But you can get empty WC from the same root as root of your directory tree, add tree from inversioned path into this WC and compare (modified WC vs URL). Read about `--depth` and `--set-depth` options also

Comment: Being able to compare files not in the repo or working copy would be a nice enhancement to Subversion. Yes, I know there is diff and fc; neither of which will inherently read from an http reference.